# View Android Chrome Cache files on device?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, chrome-for-android, cache

Is there any way to view the chrome app cache files on android without ADB or root just on the device itself?

Edit: or from a file manager on a computer?

Edit 2: does chrome use or cache different resources than the desktop version, such as loading google services?

Thank you!

Comment: For first part, No. For second part, what are you trying to do with that information? What problem is it that you want to solve?

Comment: Meaning no from neither the device nor plugged into a computer? Would root wipe this cache? I wanted to see if I could get any cached google keep web cache data from my android device.

Comment: My ultimate question is if I went to google.com on android, no matter the browser, would it have prefetched any of my keep notes without me having actually gone to the website recently with no keep app installed.